# XML data and C#, reading in, manipulating, outputting

Tags: c#, xml

I'm a C# beginner, more or less. (also an xml beginner >.<) I'm building a program for a buddy that I plan to use as my "practical program" for teaching myself C# (and xml). I'm a college student, getting a BiS in Computer Information Systems(focusing in C#). The school doesn't teach much (mostly stays in console, has an intro to c# and an intro to oop with C#).

The desire of my friend(client) is to have a program that creates/generates characters. It should read info in from xml files (for the tabletop RPG l5r, so things like skills and descriptions,advantages and bonuses to stats/skills, etc), manipulates some of the data(when there's a bonus or addition of a skill to the character,adds whats relevant to the character being created.) Calculates and displays the stats, skill levels etc., and allows for new entries into the xml files (for when he feels like creating new content).

I opted to go with XML as the "data in" as it will be more portable, and easier for non programmers to take a look at (also I'm creating the xml templates and sending them to him to fill in all the data).

I'm basically asking if there are any good websites or books that will specifically focus on reading in xml (some entries will be integer, most will be strings, not sure if I can set something as type int in xml or if I'll have to specifically parse from char to int in c# at this point) and also focus on file maintanence (add,change,delete) and how to sort xml by various child elements.

My template in xml currently looks something like

```
<skills>
    <sk1>
        <name>...</name>
        <description>...</description>
    </sk1>
    <sk2>
    etc...
```

I'm writing the first version of the program using console, but the 2nd part will be a windows gui (learning as I go along).

Any nudges in the right direction will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much for any help.

(if any further info is needed, I'll be checking this thread religiously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for xml serialization.

which means:

1. You create c# objects which reflects your game environment(skills etc...), your ood classes should help you with that
2. you take any c# objects to serialize them to XML (which is gona be your template in this case) example: [xml serializing](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=173)
3. you manipulate the values in the XML file (by hand or an application)
4. you deserialize the xml file (search for xml deserialization) to obtain the objects with the changed properties

Answer (score 2):

How about Linq to XML. There si plenty information about it

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx
2. http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx